# How to store the value of async function to a global variable in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, aws-amplify

So I have a use case of fetching emails of people logged in using the below code and pass it to the backend DB. Is there a way to store the output of the below code (expected scenario shown in subsequent code) in a separate variable and use it later in my code? Not sure if this is a possible scenario.

**Note:** I am able to print the email in the console, but not sure how to store it in a variable as shown in my second code snippit.

```
Auth.currentSession()
.then(data => {
let idToken = data.getIdToken();
let email = idToken.payload.email;
console.log(email); 
  })
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**Expectation:**

```
    var fetch = Auth.currentSession()
    .then(data => {
    let idToken = data.getIdToken();
    let email = idToken.payload.email;
    console.log(email); 
      })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  
  
async function addData() {
  const data = {
    body: {
      account_id: formState.account_id,
      builder: fetch,
    },
  };

  console.log(data);
  const apiData = await API.post("testapi", "/test", data);
  console.log({ apiData });
  alert("Request Submitted");
}
```

Comment: Kind of depends on the current context that the code is being executed in, the simplest way would be to store the email object on the window, ie `window.email =   idToken.payload.email` but that's more of a hack that should be avoided. How/ where do you expect to use the email object? Are you in a class component, function component, etc?

Comment: You can use `redux` to store values globally. But it will be only for that `session`.

Comment: @t_killah - I am using it in a function component `builder: fetch`

Comment: @t_killah - The only problem with `window.email` is once I use it outside `Auth.currentSession()` it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

@t_killah - Thank you, I was later able to resolve this using `window.email`.

```
 Auth.currentSession()
  .then((data) => {
    let idToken = data.getIdToken();
    window.email = idToken.payload.email;
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

async function addData() {
  const data = {
    body: {
      builder: window.email,
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in context, and then your data will be available globally. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext